# return outside function, or unexpected indent

Tags: python, return, indentation

I have this:

```
if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
         colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
return image, image.get_rect()
```

It tells me that "return" is outside the function.

When I change it to this:

```
if colorkey is not None:
        if colorkey is -1:
         colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
    return image, image.get_rect()
```

It just tells me that there is an unexpected indent. How do I get around this?

Comment: Are those statements inside a function?

Comment: Impossible to read. Please format your code correctly.

Comment: Can you edit your post to typeset code properly and show the indentation as it is in your file? (indent by 4 spaces to have it be rendered as code)

Comment: Done. It should be readable now.

Comment: your post is ill formated, it's not clear where you've placed indents

Comment: Don't post a different question, just edit the code in your q. ot include the def line.

Comment: You say they are inside a function, but you did not post a function definition. Seeing the entire function, definition AND body, will help us tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

In python, scopes are defined by the same level of indentation instead of braces (i.e. `{}`) as in other languages.

If you write a function, you need to ensure that all function body is at the same level of indentation - be it the same amount of spaces **or** the same amount of tabs (mixing spaces and tabs can result in real mess).

In your case, the correct indentation would look similar to (I do not know exactly, because you didn't post the code for whole function):

```
def function():
<indent>if colorkey is not None:
<indent><indent>if colorkey is -1:
<indent><indent><indent>colorkey = image.get_at((0,0))
<indent>image.set_colorkey(colorkey, RLEACCEL)
<indent>return image, image.get_rect()
```

Answer (score 0):

after `if colorkey is not None:` there are 2 indents, it needs only one

Comment: Well, it's actually 8 spaces, which could be 1, 2, 4, or 8 indents.  Given that the next line starts with 9 spaces, it seems most likely to be 8 indents.  But in any case python doesn't care, as it interprets it as only one.

Comment: Learn something about the lexing process before discussing this. It is exactly one indent in any case. The previous line is indented with `x` spaces; the current line is indented by `y` spaces; `x < y` -> one `indent` token is added. End of story.

Comment: @delnan: There are multiple ways to interpret the word "indent".  My reference to multiple indents was in the context of an editor.  I did say that "python ... interprets it as only one".

Comment: @recursive: Yes, although in the context of this question I think we should agree to use "indent" only for what Python consideres this. Python generates syntax errors and it doesn't care how many spaces OP's text editor uses.